# Sql Server - Variables inside select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

there's any way to declare and use variables INSIDE a select statement?
my idea is to use several times the same nested select for diferent math operations.

i'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and here is some example:

```
--Example Table
declare @product_table table(id int, name varchar(20), price int, active bit)
insert into @product_table
values
(1,'productA',100,1),
(2,'productB',50,1),
(3,'productC',20,0),
(4,'productD',300,1),
(5,'productE',80,0)

select
name,
(select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 1), -- <-- Declare this as a Variable
(select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 1),
(select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 1/ price),
(select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 0)
from @product_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` for this:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT (select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 1) AS Sum1
          ,(select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 0) AS Sum0
)
select
    name,
    Sum1,
    Sum1 / price,
    sum0
from @product_table
cross join cte;
```

The CTE will return one single row thus `CROSS JOIN` will just add it to the result set.

If you need computed values depending on row-values, you can reach something similar with `CROSS APPLY` to calculate values *row-by-row* and use them with a speaking name.

Just to show the principles. If your computation would include some row values, you can use `cross apply` to get *variables*:

```
select
    name,
    Sum1,
    Sum1 / price,
    sum0
from @product_table
cross apply
(
    SELECT (select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 1) AS Sum1
          ,(select sum(price) from @product_table where active = 0) AS Sum0
) A
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply your query using window functions:

```
select name,
       sum(case when active = 1 then price end) over () as price_1,
       sum(case when active = 1 then price end) over () / price as ratio,
       sum(case when active = 0 then price end) over () as price_0
from @product_table;
```

You can do what you want using subqueries or CTEs.  However, you should learn to use the best functions for what you want to do.

Comment: i've never used "over ()" before... do you have any more info?

Comment: @Chaco . . . you can start with the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Declare a Variable Inside a `SELECT` Statement, but Instead, you can Declare it outside and use it in the `SELECT`. Like this :

```
declare @product_table table(id int, name varchar(20), price int, active bit)
DECLARE @SumPrice1 INT,@SumPrice0 INT
insert into @product_table
values
(1,'productA',100,1),
(2,'productB',50,1),
(3,'productC',20,0),
(4,'productD',300,1),
(5,'productE',80,0)

SELECT 
    @SumPrice1 = sum(price) 
    from @product_table where active = 1

SELECT 
    @SumPrice0 = sum(price) 
    from @product_table where active = 0

select
name,
@SumPrice1, 
@SumPrice1,
(@SumPrice1/ price),
@SumPrice0
from @product_table
```

Or Like This

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        active,
        SumAmt = SUM(price)
        FROM @product_table
            GROUP BY active
)
SELECT
    PT.[Name],
    [1] SumAmt,
    [1] SumAmt,
    [1] /price SumAmtPrice,
    [0] ZeroSum
    FROM @product_table PT
    JOIN CTE
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(SumAmt)
        FOR
        Active IN
        (
            [0],[1]
        )
    )P
    ON 1=1
```

Or More Simply Like This

```
SELECT
    [name],
    SUM(CASE Active WHEN 1 THEN Price ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Active) ActiveSum,
    SUM(CASE Active WHEN 0 THEN Price ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Active) ZeroSum
    FROM @product_table
```

Comment: Then the Last one should do the job

Comment: yes, but this was just a example... i have a much bigger nested select that  i would like to minify.. and i guess the WITH CTE approaches better.